# Looping and storing player name prompts until an X amount is met

Tags: vb.net

I have ten case statements and each one are based on amount of players. Games 1, 3, and 5 are single player games. Games 2, 4, and 6 are two player games, and games 7, 8 , 9, and 10 are four player games.

I'm trying to figure out how to use loop to prompt the user for the corresponding players for the selected game, and a loop to display the players.

I've tried several things, and I am not really sure how to loop it X amount of times and display it.

```
            Do
        If gamenum = 1 Or 3 Or 5 Then
            Console.WriteLine($"{vbCrLf}Enter player name.")
            player1 = Console.ReadLine
            Exit Do
        ElseIf gamenum = Nothing Then

            If gamenum = 2 Or 4 Or 6 Then
                Console.WriteLine($"{vbCrLf}Enter player names.")
                player1 = Console.ReadLine
                player2 = Console.ReadLine
            ElseIf gamenum = Nothing Then

                If gamenum = 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10 Then
                ElseIf gamenum = Nothing Then
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: Simply add a `PlayerCount` variable that you set based on the value of `gamenum` and use it as a loop counter.

Comment: `If gamenum = 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10` should probably be `If gamenum = 7 Or gamenum = 8 Or gamenum = 9 Or gamenum = 10`. The same applies for all the other conditions.

Comment: @daShier Can I see an example? I'm a visual learner.

Comment: If you have variables defined for Player1 to Player4, what exactly are you looping?

Comment: I removed them, it's just 1 single player variable. I need it to prompt and save X amount of times, based on the case they selected. @Anu6is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this.
Using a list to store all player names.

```vb
Dim players As New List(Of String) 'Stores all player names
Dim playerCount As Integer = 0     'Then number of players for this game

'Determine the required number of players based on gamenum
Select Case gamenum
    Case 1, 3, 5
        playerCount = 1
    Case 2, 4, 6
        playerCount = 2
    Case 7 To 10
        playerCount = 4
    Case Else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid game choice!")
        Exit Sub
End Select

'Request players to enter their names
For i = 1 To playerCount
    Console.WriteLine($"{vbCrLf}Player {i}, enter your name")
    players.Add(Console.ReadLine)
Next

Console.WriteLine($"{vbCrLf}Total players registered: {players.Count}")

For i = 0 To players.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {players(i)}")
Next
```

Comment: How would I display the names entered in the list now? totalplayers = player.? and then console.writeline @anu6is

Comment: `totalPlayers = players.Count()` and simply access the list indexes to get the player names `player(0)` would be index 0 containing the first name. Example: `Console.WriteLine($"Welcome player1 - {players(0)}"). I modified the example to show the total players an greet each one by name.

Comment: To make sure I understand this all, I'm going to explain how I interpret this code. For i = 1 to playercount means it will prompt the user for names until it reaches the max playercount, as defined in the case statement. It will store each one in the player.add list. Every time the code runs, {i} will increment in the console.writeline and display properly. after the first loop, another console.writeline is used and it displays the players.count, so total number people registered.

Comment: In the second loop i will increment to the players.count and display a console.writeline. I just don't know what the "- 1" means after the players.count.

Comment: Ok, so your understanding is correct. As far as the `-1` goes, I would assume you haven't done much with arrays or collections in general with VB. All collections including the list used in this code start at **index 0**. However the count indicates how much items are actually in the list. So, if you have a list with 1 item, the count is `1` but that item is held in `index 0`. The reason you do `-1` when iterating through a collection is because the valid accessible indexes stop at **collection size -1**.  A collection with 2 items has index 0 & index 1. There is no index 2, however count is 2